# How to specify number of GPUs in Python interface?

Tags: tensorflow

When I start a [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) `Session` it immediately allocates 100% of the memory on both GPUs in my dekstop (devices 0 and 2).

How can I use the [Python API](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/index.md) to restrict it to just 1 GPU?

Comment: What do you mean to specify the number of GPUs? If you tell number `4` what do you want to happen?

Comment: If they have different power, you could use TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT. For instance, I have GeForce GT 730 and Tesla K40, if I do export TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT=8, then only my K40 is being used (730 has 2 streaming multiprocessors)

Comment: Another trick to stop TF from grabbing all GPU memory, use config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction as here https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#155

Comment: If Salvador Dali provided a correct answer is it proper StackOverflow etiquette to accept the answer and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A crude way to restrict it to use just GPU #0, for example, is to define this:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want some operations to be done only with a particular device, you can do the following:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
   ...
   # all your operations
```

Where the devices are specified in the following way: `"/cpu:0"`, `"/gpu:0"`, `"/gpu:1"`. I suggest you to read more details in the topic [using GPU devices](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/index.md).

If you want to see some tutorials, take a look at [cifar10 tutorial.](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.md)